# Unique usernames in Devise for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed [Devise's instructions for using usernames in addition to emails](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) for logins. Works great except people can signup with duplicate usernames. If someone tries to signup with a duplicate email address, they are presented with this error message on the signup page:

> 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> ```
> Email has already been taken
> ```

I want something very similar for usernames. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use uniqueness validator. Add following into user.rb:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username
```

[more about this validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness)

Comment: Perfect, the error message is exactly what I'd hoped it would be: "Username has already been taken".

Comment: I think this won't work when you change your username, and then want to change it back, that is - when you want to edit your profile.

For example, if you want to change your username from abc to abc1 it will work, but if you want to change it back to abc and hit the update button, you will get the 'Username has already been taken' error

Comment: @Nicholas I believe you're creating two models in your code or there's some other issue involved.

Answer (score 7):

Note that you probably want to make usernames unique, *but also case-insensitive*, so you don't end up with both username and Username:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  # Rest of user model
end
```

From the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).